# C# Console Application breaks?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace heavynumbers2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HeavyDeciCount();
            int firstNumber;
            int secondNumber;
            Console.Write("Enter First Number: ");
            firstNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter Second Number: ");
            secondNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        public static void HeavyDeciCount(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
        {
            var totalHeavyCount = 0;
            for (int i = firstNumber; i <= secondNumber; i++)
            {
                var avg = i.ToString()
                    .Select(o => Convert.ToInt32(o.ToString()))
                    .ToArray()
                    .Average();
                var isHeavy = false;
                if (avg > 7)
                {
                    isHeavy = true;
                    totalHeavyCount++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("HeavyNumbers" + "Average" + "IsHeavy");
                Console.WriteLine(i + "    " + avg + "    " +    (isHeavy ? "Yes" : "No"));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total Heavy Count: " + totalHeavyCount);
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Close Program ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I run this program and when i try to call the method in main method, The compiler says:

> no overload method define for your `heavydeciCount` method

and program closes abnormally.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Your method accepts 2 arguments:

```
public static void HeavyDeciCount(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
```

You pass it 0:

```
HeavyDeciCount(); // no arguments are being passed
```

You probably wanted to have your code rearranged like so:

```
int firstNumber;
int secondNumber;
Console.Write("Enter First Number: ");
firstNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter Second Number: ");
secondNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

HeavyDeciCount(firstNumber, secondNumber); // you call the method with 2 numbers after you already have them
```

The problem the compiler is complaining about is that it expects to find an [*overloaded*](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) method to `HeavyDeciCount` that accepts 0 arguments, but no such method exists.

Comment: I am passing int firstNumber, int secondNumber as parameters and i dont know why it is not accepting. They have red line below it. If you know how to resolve it please guide me.

Comment: @BilalMujahid I edited my answer with further explanation and code that will work for you. Also take a read of the link to understand method overloading.

Comment: Now how to call the method kindly could u please explain by typing the method.

Comment: I did explain and showed you. The call is: `HeavyDeciCount(firstNumber, secondNumber);` . You call the method with 2 arguments exactly like you declared and implemented it.

Comment: Beat me to posting the same answer @Idos !. To expand: you're calling your `HeavyDeciCount()` in the OP question, _before_ you had any values to give anyway. (including the fact there is not method signature for `HeavyDeciCount()` with no arguments) :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the parameters needed to your method. Call the method after getting `firstNumber` and `secondNumber`, and pass them to it.

So change the main method like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int firstNumber;
        int secondNumber;
        Console.Write("Enter First Number: ");
        firstNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter Second Number: ");
        secondNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

       HeavyDeciCount(firstNumber,secondNumber);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Now i have figured out. Alex how can i follow you on this website when i have some programming error like this i can take guidance from you then.

Comment: I don't think There's any follow option on StackOverFlow. But you can Email me whenever you want. I'd be happy to help. You can find then email on my profile